# Three.js AWS S3 CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, three.js, cors

I'm trying to use an image from a AWS S3 bucket as a texture in three.js. I get the following error -

> Access to Image at 'https://s3-a...' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have set my CORS settings so there is no issue viewing the images in an  tag. Following Three.js threads I've also tried using

```
myImage.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
myImage.crossOrigin = "" 
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = ""
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
```

**Update:** CORS settings on s3 bucket are as follows -

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Being able to load the image using the img tag doesn’t mean you’ve got CORS set up correctly on the server. Cross-origin img elements work fine without CORS.

Comment: Try using curl or something to request the image and check the response headers. For example, `curl -i -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000/" https://s3-a/path-to-image`. If you don’t see an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response from that then CORS is not configured correctly on the server.

Comment: Does CORS work with the hostname `localhost`?  I don't think it does.  Try updating the cors config and using `http://lvh.me:3000` to access your test site.  The lvh.me hostname is a test that is equivalent to "localhost."  You can also use www.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3000, and there are probably others.

Comment: Your right, there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the response header. Can't find any documentation that states how to s3 to add this when serving images. I would of thought you could do it through an <ExposeHeader> tag but there no documentation relating to cross-origin http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

Comment: Does it still fail if you use an `http://` URL for the image instead of an `https://` URL? If you remove the `<AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
` and  `<AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>` lines from your CORS config XML document does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using **ImageUtils** instead of **textureLoader**. I think ImageUtils is deprecated...

Comment: can you share the working code please? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured CORS on the S3 bucket?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: yeah and I assume it is correct considering I can load an image via an <img> element